# Subroutine erroneously removes remaining column data when removing duplicate rows

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, listboxitem

I'm re-engineering a subroutine to remove the duplicate rows from a listbox; the "ColumnCount" property of the listbox is set to "13". If I don't call my duplicate removal subroutine, the listbox correctly contains all of the columns of data; however, several rows are dupliated. The subroutine is listed below:

```
Private Sub RemoveDuplicateListBoxRows()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim nodupes As New Collection
    Dim Swap1, Swap2, Item

    With Me.lbSrchMatchingResults

        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            ' The next statement ignores the error caused
            ' by attempting to add a duplicate key to the collection.
            ' The duplicate is not added - which is just what we want!
            On Error Resume Next
            nodupes.Add .List(i), CStr(.List(i))
        Next i

    '   Resume normal error handling
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Clear the listbox
        .Clear

        'Sort the collection (optional)
        For i = 1 To nodupes.Count - 1
            For j = i + 1 To nodupes.Count
                If nodupes(i) > nodupes(j) Then
                    Swap1 = nodupes(i)
                    Swap2 = nodupes(j)
                    nodupes.Add Swap1, before:=j
                    nodupes.Add Swap2, before:=i
                    nodupes.Remove i + 1
                    nodupes.Remove j + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

    '   Add the sorted and non-duplicated items to the ListBox
        For Each Item In nodupes
            .AddItem Item
        Next Item

    End With
End Sub
```

The problem begins with the following line of code:

```
nodupes.Add .List(i), CStr(.List(i))
```

It's only adding the first column of my 13-column worksheet to the collection variable "nodupes". I would like to add an entire row from the worksheet to the sheet. How do I modify my collection to accept a complete row of data, not just the first cell of a row, such that listbox is properly reconstructed when the following code is executed?

```
 For Each Item In nodupes
      .AddItem Item
 Next Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

What it does is to drop the whole contents of the listbox onto a worksheet, use the Remove Duplicates function to de-dupe it, and then just load it back into the listbox.

Dim ary As Variant

```
ary = Me.lbSrchMatchingResults.List

With Worksheets("scratch")

    .UsedRange.ClearContents
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ary, 1) - LBound(ary, 1) + 1, UBound(ary, 2) - LBound(ary, 2) + 1) = ary

    .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

    Me.lbSrchMatchingResults.List = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
End With
```

Comment: Must I create a new worksheet named "scratch" or will VBA automatically create it if it doesn't exist?

Comment: The code I gave assumed scratch will exist. Do you want me to update it so that the VBA creates and removes it?

Comment: No, I can figure it out. Thanks for your help.